# Sum Filtered/Visible Data only VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum, subtotal

I have a VBA script that was very kindly [provided by another member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24935099/summing-values-in-filtered-rows-only).

Since requesting help, I have realised that I need to sum just the data in the visible cells as the SUBTOTAL function does (e.g. if a filter is applied). I have attempted to insert `xlCellTypeVisible` but have not had much luck (still new to VBA!). The context behind this macro can be found by reading the thread in the above link.

Can anyone help with the correct code?

```
 Function maxUniqueWithThresholda(ids As Range, vals As Range, _
                                 dates As Range, thold As Long)
     Static d As Object, i As Long

     'create a dictionary for unique ids only if not previously created
     If d Is Nothing Then Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     d.RemoveAll

     'limit the processing ranges
     Set ids = Intersect(ids, ids.Parent.UsedRange)
     Set vals = vals.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)
     Set dates = dates.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)

     'cycle through the processing ranges
     For i = 1 To ids.Cells.Count
         'is date within threshold?
         If dates.Cells(i) <= thold And xlCellTypeVisible Then
             'collect the maximum value for each unique id into dictionary Items
             d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2) = _
               Application.Max(d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2), vals.Cells(i).Value2)
         End If
     Next i

     maxUniqueWithThresholda = Application.Sum(d.items)

 End Function
```

Many thanks for any help in advance

Comment: If dates.Cells(i) <= thold And dates.Cells(1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then

Comment: @MichalRosa - you shouldn't have to compare a boolean to a boolean constant to determine a boolean result. `... And Not dates.Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden` should be sufficient. (note **i** not **1**)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michal and user 10735198 for your input:

```
Function maxUniqueWithThresholda(ids As Range, vals As Range, _
                            dates As Range, thold As Long)
Static d As Object, i As Long

'create a dictionary for unique ids only if not previously created
If d Is Nothing Then Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
d.RemoveAll

'limit the processing ranges
Set ids = Intersect(ids, ids.Parent.UsedRange)
Set vals = vals.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)
Set dates = dates.Resize(ids.Rows.Count, ids.Columns.Count)

'cycle through the processing ranges
For i = 1 To ids.Cells.Count
    'is date within threshold?
    If dates.Cells(i) <= thold And dates.Cells(i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
        'collect the maximum value for each unique id into dictionary Items
        d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2) = _
          Application.Max(d.Item(ids.Cells(i).Value2), vals.Cells(i).Value2)
    End If
Next i

maxUniqueWithThresholda = Application.Sum(d.items)

End Function
```